# I want to serve a wordpress login widget only to selected Ip addresses is this possible?

Tags: wordpress

I have a ajax login widget on a wordpress site thing is only me and the other admin need to see It so I was wondering if there is a way to only serve this widget to my ip address and the other admin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so using .htaccess by allowing only certain IP addresses to access your wp-login.php

```
<Files wp-login.php>
  Order Deny,Allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from xx.xx.xx.xx
</Files>
```

Update:
If you want to control who views the widget, you can use a conditional statement using PHP's $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] to get the visitors IP address. If it matches some address, then you display the widget.

Comment: Thank you that will work for preventing access to the login page, but I am trying to hide a login widget that sits in the footer from all visitors apart from the two admin is this possible with htaccess

Comment: That sounds great unfortunately my php is very basic, would this go in functions.php. Sorry the most php i do normally is includes or echo statements

Comment: If someone could poit me in the right direction I will figure the rest out

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to give more info about the widget to be able to help you. Is it a plugin? Which one?

Comment: Its the login with ajax plugin i have it showing in the footer at this address [link]http://www.paintedroom.co.uk

Comment: Is there no one who knows the answer

Comment: You need to show codes, only showing the page won't be of much help.

Comment: I dodn't because its an existing plugin on wordpress with many files I thought by showing the name of the plugin you could look it up from there